# in laravel, is there any good way to plunk object properties in array of objects & remove unnecessary properties in request

Tags: php, laravel

```
{
  "city_name": "new cityName",
  "country_id": 3,
  "localities": [
    {
      "name": "locality 11",
      "postal-code": 123456,
      "locality-specialized-in": "FOOD,TECH",
      "extra_data" : "unwanted, unnecessary data"
    },
    {
      "name": "locality 21",
      "postal-code": "1234567",

      "extra_data" : "unwanted, unnecessary data",
      "extra_data_two" : "unwanted, unnecessary data"
    }
  ]
}
```

in above request just want to plunk`localities` with only fields(`name`,`postal-code`) and want to remove extra fields (like as per above request `locality-specialized-in`).
just thing is without using loop or any good manner

expected filter data from above request

```
$localities_array = [
    [
      "name"=> "locality 11",
      "postal-code"=> 123456
    ],
    [
      "name"=> "locality 21",
      "postal-code"=> 1234567
    ]
]
```

currently i am using below method in controller to archive this.

```
$localities = null;
foreach (request()->get('localities') as $locality) {
    $localities[] = ["name"=>$locality['name'],"postal-code"=>$locality['postal-code'] ];
}
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code in your controller where you populate your initial array.

Comment: @dipen You should show us controller code.

Comment: To be clear, you want to achieve this without looping?

Comment: Yes. Exactly...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get value from array in request use the below code.

```
 $localities = null;
 $localities['name'] = request()->get('localities.name');
 $localities['postal-code'] = request()->get('localities.postal-code');
```

Comment: ```localities``` is array of objects not just nested data. so here we not able cant use ```request()->get('localities.name');``` syntax.

Comment: @Dipen Have you tried the above logic? How you have posted data from HTML form? Means your blade view.

Comment: I am receiving data in above format as I mentioned in the question . & I am dealing with APIs, not blade